# How to wait for a forEach to finish before returning from my promise / function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, promise

Angular, firestore

I have an angular function to get products from one firestore collection, then I am looping over the results of that query to lookup prices from another collection.

How can I wait until the prices forEach is done before returning from the outer promise and the outer function itself?

The returned result contains a products array, but the prices array for each product is empty.

```
 const products = await this.billingService.getProducts();
```

```
async getProducts() {
    let result = [];
    let product = {};
    return this.db.collection(
      'products',
      ref => { ref
        let query: Query = ref;
          return query.where('active', '==', true)
      })
      .ref
      .get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async function (doc) {
          product = doc.data();
          product['prices'] = [];

          await doc.ref
            .collection('prices')
            .orderBy('unit_amount')
            .get()
            .then(function (docs) {
              // Prices dropdown
              docs.forEach(function (doc) {
                const priceId = doc.id;
                const priceData = doc.data();
                product['prices'].push(priceData);
              });
            });
        });
        result.push(product);
        return result;
      });
  }
```

I also tried this approach, but not sure how to access the results

```
await this.billingService.getProducts().then(results =>
```

```
getProducts() {
      const dbRef =
        this.db.collection(
          'products',
          ref => { ref
            let query: Query = ref; return query.where('active', '==', true)
        });
       const dbPromise = dbRef.ref.get();

      return dbPromise
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
          let results = [];
          let product = {};
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            let docRef = doc.ref
              .collection('prices')
              .orderBy('unit_amount')
              results.push(docRef.get())
          });
          return Promise.all(results)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: async/await does not work the way you expect in a forEach loop.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Stop using `.forEach()`.  It is not async or promise aware.  Use a regular `for` loop intead.

Comment: @jfriend00 `for(const doc of querySnapshot) {`  Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

Comment: @dak - `querySnapshot.docs` is an array you should be able to use.  See [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the getProducts() function a promise. Thus it will only return when you resolve it ( or reject it).

```
getProducts() {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
let result = [];
let product = {};
this.db.collection(
  'products',
  ref => { ref
    let query: Query = ref;
      return query.where('active', '==', true)
  })
  .ref
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(async function (doc) {
      product = doc.data();
      product['prices'] = [];

      doc.ref
        .collection('prices')
        .orderBy('unit_amount')
        .get()
        .then(function (docs) {
          // Prices dropdown
          docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            const priceId = doc.id;
            const priceData = doc.data();
            product['prices'].push(priceData);
          });
          resolve(result);// returns when it reaches here
        });
    });
    result.push(product);
  });
 })
}
```

Then you can call the promise using then or await

```
this.billingService.getProducts().then( res => {
 const products = res;
})
```

Using await

```
const products = await this.billingService.getProducts();
```

Comment: Multiple issues.

Comment: I was just showing like he can use a promise to do it. He just has to resolve in the correct place. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a Community Wiki answer, based in the comments.

For this case, using a `forEach()` is not the correct choice. As clarified in this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), `forEach()` doesn't work properly with `await` functions, this way, not working correctly with your promises. Considering that and the fact that you want to read the data in sequence - as the results from one query will impact in the second one - you need to use a normal `for`, to loop through the data and arrays. This specific answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/12767257) should help you with code samples.

Answer (score 1):

This version of the code works:

```
  getProducts(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
      let result = [];
      let product = {};
      this.db.collection(
        'products',
        ref => { ref
          let query: Query = ref;
          return query.where('active', '==', true)
        })
        .ref
        .get()
        .then(async function (querySnapshot:firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) {
          for(const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
            const priceSnap = await doc.ref
              .collection('prices')
              .orderBy('unit_amount')
              .get()
            product = doc.data();
            product['prices'] = [];
            // Prices dropdown
            for(const doc of priceSnap.docs) {
              const priceId = doc.id;
              let priceData = doc.data();
              priceData['price_id'] = priceId;
              product['prices'].push(priceData);
              resolve(result);// returns when it reaches here
            };
            result.push(product);
          };
        });
    })
  }
```